# How to do Hibernate query using like and %?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a Hibernate SQL query like this:

```
public void funcA(String str) {
  StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
  sql.append("select fieldA from tableA where fieldB like '%:searchKey%'");

  ...

  session.createSQLQuery(sql.toString())
  .addScalar("fieldA", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
  .setParameter("searchKey", str);

  ...
}
```

when I make a query like this `query.list()`, I got following error:

```
[WARNING ] SQL Error: -7, SQLState: 42601[ERROR   ] The character "%" following "fieldB like" is not valid.
[ERROR   ] An error occurred during implicit system action type "2".  Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-7", SQLSTATE "42601" and message tokens "%|fieldB like".
```

May I know how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this should work:

```
    public void funcA(String str) {
  StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
  sql.append("select fieldA from tableA where fieldB like :searchKey");

  ...

  session.createSQLQuery(sql.toString())
  .addScalar("fieldA", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
  .setParameter("searchKey", "%" + str + "%");

  ...
}
```

Comment: what if fieldA is a Long or non-string?  Then hibernate doesn't like the string.  I still want to do a "fuzzy" match (ie. contains using %%) but the column is a Long.  Mysql queries are fine with this, but it doesn't seem that hibernate is.

Comment: above code is not working for me. any other alternative?

Answer (score 5):

In the same example, i have used [MatchMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html#END) (class of hibernate, to deal with like predicate restrictions).

```
 public void funcA(String str) {
  StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
  sql.append("select fieldA from tableA where fieldB like :searchKey");

  ...
  session.createSQLQuery(sql.toString())
  .addScalar("fieldA", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
  .setParameter("searchKey", MatchMode.ANYWHERE.toMatchString(str));

  ...
}
```

> MatchMode.ANYWHERE.toMatchString(str) : toMatchString method converts the value string to enum from which it is called.

Options:

- ANYWHERE: '%' + value + '%'
- END: '%' + value
- START: value + '%'
- EXACT: value

Answer (score 3):

For us this works...

```
    whereCluase += " and lower(" + firstAttribute + ") like ?";
    queryParams.add("%" + value.toLowerCase() + "%");
```

Sorry for posting a small snippet. But this should be enough to get you out of trouble.

**EDIT**: from comment, `lower` and `toLowerCase()` is to implement case-in sensitiveness here.

Comment: +1 Note all the `lower()`/`toLowerCase()` is just an example how to match case-insensitively. It's not necessary in this case.